# In macvim, can i keep cmdheight=1, without getting a prompt before opening some files?

Tags: vim, macvim

In vim, can i keep cmdheight=1, without getting a prompt before opening some files?

My issue is that if I do

```
~/whatever$ vi app/controllers/application_controller.rb
```

Then because `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` is too big  for a terminal size of 80x24 , I get a prompt.

I could make the terminal 85 width, but i'm looking for other options.

[image]

I notice the screen says x lines y characters.  If it said y char instead of characters then it'd perhaps fit.  But even so, there seems to be a lot of unused width  within the terminal so I don't really see why the terminal width is considered too narrow, 'justifying' a 'prompt'.

I don't even see the connection between the length of a path-filename, and being prompted to open the file.

I have done  `:h hit-enter` or `:help hit-enter` and got http://vimhelp.appspot.com/message.txt.html#hit-enter and it mentioned about `:set cmdheight=2` but that looks ugly 'cos it leads to a blank line on the bottom. And it even does so on files where I wouldn't get a prompt i.e. on files whose path-filenames are short enough that vim doesn't give me a prompt before opening them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to change cmdheight from the default of 1.

this fixes it

`set shortmess+=l`

So now if it were to prompt, e.g. if the terminal was too narrow, it says 5L 16C  instead of 5 lines 16 characters, and that then means that `vi app/controllers/application_controller.rb` will not lead to a prompt on a terminal of width 80.

Now even with a terminal of width 70, it won't wrap. (though 69 it will wrap).

A default shortmess used in some places  https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2001/03/msg01028.html  is longer e.g.  `set shortmess=filnxtToO` and one can add `I` to that. But notice that default includes `l`. So with that default one wouldn't have an issue.

My shortmess was set to `I`(which is a good setting, and removes brad's screed), but was missing the `l`(el, lowercase). So e.g. `shortmess=Il`

Doing `:set shortmess?` will show the current value of shortmess.